# Why 9BBN's rings don't migrate during hydroboration-oxidation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

My organic chemistry textbook (Clayden, Warren, Greeves) says this:

> If we use the $\ce{HBR2}$ reagent $\ce{9-BBN}$, then only the
> non-cyclic substituent formed in the hydroboration reaction will
> migrate, selectively giving us the product we want.

Why can't the original substituents of $\ce{9-BBN}$ migrate? It seems to me that there is nothing stopping the rings of $\ce{9-BBN}$ from migrating to the oxygen in the $\ce{-OOH}$ attached to the Boron.

Comment: I suspect the ring strain raises the energy of the transition state enough that those migrations are disfavored.

Comment: I agree. 9-BBN is a pretty rigid molecule, which is exactly why is it used